# How to configure Airflow for writing logs to Blob storage?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, airflow, devops

I'm trying to follow this article: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/howto/write-logs.html
so Airflow will start writing logs to blob storage but the problem is I do not now how to configure Airflow to do that. In my case, Airflow is running on Kubernetes Cluster and deployment is done via Helm chart.

I tried to log into webserver Pod but @airflow user is not authorized to create any files in AIRFLOW_HOME directory. I was trying to use sudo but I can't find password (I'm not even sure if it works airflow is not in sudoers anyway )

Should I do all of this in docker image and just restart Airflow?

Comment: Are you using 1.10.6? Because the link you shared is for 1.10.x version. If you are using Kubernetes it is a good idea to move the logs to S3 or GCS.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/core-extensions/logging.html

Comment: Yea I know it would be best but I also wanted to check how wirint to stdout or stderr would work for us.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with Helm Chart setups but maybe it is worth a try to add the variables for remote logging in the values.yaml file like this:

```yaml
config: 
    logging:
        remote_logging=True
        log_conn_id=<their AWS conn id>
        remote_base_log_folder=s3://bucket-name/logs
```

Plus define a normal Airflow connection either via an ENV variable in the Dockerfile or via the UI and provide that as the AWS conn id.

If that does not work my next attempt would be to use ENV variables for all of the settings in the Dockerfile:

```
# allow remote logging and provide a connection ID
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING=True
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=${AMAZONS3_CON_ID}

# specify the location of your remote logs using your bucket name
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3://${S3BUCKET_NAME}/logs

# optional: serverside encryption for S3 logs
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__ENCRYPT_S3_LOGS=True
```

Also if you are on pre-2 Airflow consider upgrading if you can, it is worth it imho. :)